NSCache singleton - concurrency safe (Swift 6)
I would like to make sure I understand this correctly. I created a singleton class managing cache of NumberFormatters and compiler complains about shared property not being concurrency-safe. Reasons are obvious to me...
However, I use the singleton just for managing NSCache. Since NSCache is thread safe, is my implementation thread safe?
Therefore, is it ok to mark shared propery: nonisolated(unsafe) to silence the warning/error?
public final class CachedNumberFormatters {
    nonisolated(unsafe) public static let shared = CachedNumberFormatters()
    let cache = NSCache<NSString, NumberFormatter>()

    private init() {}

    public func simpleNumberFormatter(for decimalSeparator: String) -> NumberFormatter {
        return cachedFormatter(decimalSeparator: decimalSeparator)
    }

    func cachedFormatter(decimalSeparator: String) -> NumberFormatter {
        if let cachedObject = cache.object(forKey: decimalSeparator as NSString) {
            return cachedObject
        } else {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.decimalSeparator = decimalSeparator
        
            cache.setObject(formatter, forKey: decimalSeparator as NSString)
            return formatter
        }
    }
}


Why not make CachedNumberFormatters an actor instead of a class?

make your init private, otherwise it's not really a singleton

@timbretimbre good point with init. Thanks - I will edit it. However, that is not really important in the context of my question.
@Paulw11 Of course, I can change it to be an Actor. Reason why I did not, is to simplify its (async) calling. But the question still remains unanswered...
